# How to set an initial value for a variable in a recursive function in Python?

Tags: python, function, recursion

This is a general problem I keep having. As I feel like this question is best asked through an example, I made up a function to illustrate the general issue I am having.

```
def function(a):
    b=56
    if a>0:
        b=b+2
        a=a-1
        return function(a)
    else:
        print(b)
```

Here, I'm trying to set an initial value for `b` that will change depending on `a`. For example, if `a=1`, I would like the function to return `58`, but it actually returns `56`. I understand that whenever the function loops back around, it resets `b` as `56`, so the function will always return `56` no matter what `a` is. I was wondering how I could set the initial value as `56` without it reseting every time.

I hope this makes sense! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:** Depending on your use case, if `b` can be a parameter to the recursion state as well. **Since `b` needs to be determined by `a`, we can set the initial value of `b` when `b is None`**

```py
def func(a, b=None):
  if b is None:
    # b is not set, determine `b` now depending on `a`
    b = 56     # fill-in other cases here   
  if a > 0:
    b += 2
    a -= 1
    return func(a, b)
  else:
    return b

func(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

The typical approach to doing this sort of thing is to have your recursive function take the "accumulator" (`b` here) as an additional parameter. Then your actual function just calls it with the desired initial value, here 56.

For your example this would be:

```
def recursive(a, b):
    if a>0:
        b=b+2
        a=a-1
        return recursive(a, b)
    else:
        print(b)

def function(a):
    return recursive(a, 56)
```

Note that you could simplify `recursive` by having the `if` statement `return recursive(a - 1, b + 2)`. And you probably want to `return b` rather than simply `print`it.